# How to change the heading (titles) text to uppercase?

Tags: html, uppercase

I'm trying to change all the titles, i.e. `h1`, `h2`, `h3`... to be `uppercase` using JavaScript.

`the white cat` should be `THE WHITE CAT`.

The method will be placed in a seperate `.js` file.

Comment: Well what did you try? And in reality zero JS is needed.

Comment: [Easier than JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform)

Comment: it is required to be in a js file.

Comment: the line is <h1><span id="katt">Katt</span></h1> i want to make it uppercase using a js separate file, i already linked the file to the html

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript you need to get reference the object using `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByClassName`. After that you can style the element by accessing the `style` property of the object, OR just set the content to be uppercase using the built in `toUpperCase()` function that JavaScript has.

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
header.innerHTML = header.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
```

```html
<h1 id="myHeader">Hello, world</h1>
```

**HOWEVER**

The easier solution is to just set a class on the whole header object, and use

`.upperCaseHeader { text-transform: uppercase}`

Or, if you know that all the header elements on your page will be uppercase, use;

`h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 { text-transform: uppercase; }`

in a CSS file.

**EDIT:** On OP's request the code is slightly changed to change the text to uppercase on button click

The function here will find all the tags of type `h1` through `h6` using [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and set all the text in them to uppercase, as you requested. Again, I would rather add a class with `text-transform` uppercase, and dynamically add and remove this class, but since you have very specific needs, I am posting this alternative solution here now.

[Here](https://codepen.io/thomasdarvik/pen/MGGwbb) is a working pen as well

```js
function setUppercase() {
  var tags = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"];
  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var allTagsOfType = document.getElementsByTagName(tags[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < allTagsOfType.length; j++) {
      allTagsOfType[j].innerText = allTagsOfType[j].innerText.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2>I am going</h2>
<h3>to be</h3>
<h4>uppercase</h4>
<h5>soon</h5>
<h6>tiny text</h6>
<button onclick="setUppercase()">Set uppercase</button>
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a button in the output html file, that changes the titles when clicked. The titles should be changed to uppercase. I have already made the button and it worked. I've made the button to change a specific word in the html file, now i need to make all headers uppercase using the js file.

Comment: You can do that on the `onclick` event of the button. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: @DhulfiqarH.Al-Hussan see updated answer to find the code you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

in your style.css

```
h2 {
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?
ref:   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp

```
var text = $('h2').text();    
var res = text.toUpperCase();
$('h2').text(res);
```

Edit--
Or you can do everything through JS and append the element. the `` are ES6 string literals.

```
var text = "The White Cat";    
var res = text.toUpperCase();
var uppercase = `<h2>${res}</h2>`;
$('body').append(uppercase);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this inline styling:

```
<h2 style="text-transform: uppercase"> The White Cate </h2>
```